# Advice on troubleshooting intermittent Wi-Fi drop outs

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I am struggling to diagnose an issue I am having with my wi-fi dropping out intermittently throughout the day and I was hoping to get some advice to try and work out what the root cause is.

Here are the facts and the various things I've tried:

1. The issue is only present on one device (Windows 11 PC).
2. My wi-fi adapter is the Intel Wireless-AC 9462
3. Ethernet works perfectly.
4. DNS on router has been set to 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4
5. I ping 192.168.1.1 to help observe drop outs. Ping timeouts coincide with drop outs.
6. Pings to google.co.uk timeout at the same time as 192.168.1.1
7. Usually, during ping timeouts, the PC remains connected to the router (according to the wi-fi taskbar icon). Sometimes it disconnects completely.
8. Usually, the drop outs cause both browsing, streaming and my online game to disconnect/refuse to load.
9. Occasionally, I observe that the pings are timing out and Chrome/Firefox refuse to load anything, but my online game is still connected and running properly.
10. Sometimes all the pings timeout but the connection is actually working fine (browser & game).
11. My current ISP (Vodafone) doesn't let me change the wi-fi channels.
12. I had the same problem with my previous ISP (TalkTalk).
13. Connecting to the wi-fi hotspot on my phone is much more stable (<1% packet loss).

I've tried:

1. Restarting my PC
2. Restarting the router & fibre box
3. Flushing my DNS (ipconfig /flushdns)
4. Disabling & enabling my wi-fi driver
5. Installing different wi-fi driver versions
6. Changing wi-fi driver settings (preferred band, roaming aggressiveness)
7. Observing router logs and Windows event logs
8. Moving my PC next to the router

Does anyone have any further ideas or tools/techniques I can use to diagnose this issue?

Comment: Where is the Wi-Fi relative to the machine with an issue? This is probably a physical environment issue and not a true Networking issue.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 The router is in the adjacent room. However, I experience the same drop outs even when I move my PC to the same room as the router with line-of-sight.

Comment: A few questions: Are you near an airport, or within the vicinity of a Radar station? Secondly, what's the make and model of your router? Confirm.

Comment: @DennisMungai I'm not near an airport, nor a radar station afaik. The router is the Vodafone VOX 3 Broadband Router.